# Split Raster Iteration or loop in R

Tags: r, loops, split, raster

R Programming Language (New to this)

I am attempting to loop through a number of tiled rasters that have been output by splitRaster. During the loop I want to carry out some processes on each raster.

But the following code throws an error.

```
library(ForestTools)
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(SpaDES)
rm(list = ls())
tmpdir <- file.path(tempdir(), "splitRaster")
lin <- function(x){x * 0.1 + 0.6}
inCHM <- raster("input raster path and name.tif")
split <- splitRaster(inCHM, 5, 5, c(0.05, 0.05), tmpdir)
files <- list.files(path=tmpdir, pattern="*.grd", full.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE)
file.names <- dir(tmpdir, pattern ="*.grd")

for(file.names in files ){
name <- file.names
ttops <- vwf(name, winFun = lin, minHeight = 5)
writeOGR(ttops, "output folder", name, driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
}
```

and this is the error

```
[1] "Xrastername_tile1.grd"
Error in CRS(x) : 
  PROJ4 argument-value pairs must begin with +: Xrastername_tile1.grd
```

---

More to the problem (24/7/2020),

I have removed the loop for trouble shooting instead just choosing one of the splitRasters outputs that would be used in the loop ie files[[3]]

When I run the following code the error is the same;

```
library(ForestTools)
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(SpaDES)
rm(list = ls())
# set temp directory
tmpdir <- "C:\\R-Test\\Temp_Output"
# get raster
r <- raster("C:\\Lidar\\grid_treeheight_max_1m_nofill.tif")
# define projection
projection(r) <- "+proj=utm +zone=50 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
# split raster brick
y <- splitRaster(r, 8, 8, c(0.05, 0.05), tmpdir)
# Get the complete file locations with full.names = T
files <- list.files(path=tmpdir, pattern="*.grd", full.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE)
tmpfile <- paste(tmpdir, "\\", files[[3]], sep="")
lin <- function(x){x * 0.06 + 0.6}
ttops <- vwf(tmpfile, winFun = lin, minHeight = 5)
```

This is the error

```
Error in CRS(x) : 
  PROJ4 argument-value pairs must begin with +: D:\R-Test\Temp_Output\Xgrid_treeheight_max_1m_nofill_tile11.grd
```

When I run the following code using one of the splitRaster outputs (files[[3]]) from the above code it runs error free and I am able to plot ttops.

```
rm(list = ls())
# set temp directory
tmpdir <- "D:\\R-Test\\Temp_Output"
# get raster
r <- raster("D:\\R-Test\\Temp_Output\\Xgrid_treeheight_max_1m_nofill_tile11.grd")
lin <- function(x){x * 0.06 + 0.6}
ttops <- vwf(r, winFun = lin, minHeight = 5)
```

Why is the PROJ4 error occurring?

This seems to be the error that is causing the loop to fail?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to feed the `vwf` function with the file name instead of a raster object. I would also recommend using `lapply` instead of `for` for the loop. Here is a code that should work

```
library(raster)
library(ForestTools)
library(rgdal)

# Get the complete file locations with full.names = T
files <- list.files(path=tmpdir, pattern="*.grd", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)

# Loop over each item of the list, i.e., each raster
lapply(files, function(x){
  # Load the image as raster
  image <- raster(x)
  # Calculate vwf (I added a dummy function for winFun)
  ttops <- vwf(image, winFun = function(x){x * 0.06 + 0.5}, minHeight = 5)
  # Write the file with the name of each raster
  writeOGR(ttops, "output_dir", names(x), driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
})
```

Comment: It appears that the names(x) variable in writeOGR is causing the loop to fail.

Comment: Maybe all the rasters have the same name? That could result in R trying to overwrite the same file. To avoid that you could create another object for the files names, something like: `names_file <- list.files(path=tmpdir, pattern="*.grd", full.names=F, recursive=FALSE)
names_file <- gsub(".grd","",names_file)` and then loop over the number of elements of files and choose the names in `writeOGR` like `names_file[i]` instead of `names(x)`

Comment: and this is the error message Error in writeOGR(ttops, "D:\\R-Test\\Temp_Output", names(x), driver = "ESRI Shapefile") : 
  CHAR() can only be applied to a 'CHARSXP', not a 'NULL'

Comment: a print(names(x) displays a number of values which consist of NULL and [[1]]NULL [[2]]NULL etc

Comment: Mmm looks like they don' have names. You could try using the other code I posted in comments